# Mock an object created in the middle of a method

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, mockery

I know that creating an instance of a `Class` in the middle of a `method` it's a bad practice since it makes code hard to test.
But I can't refactor the code, so I need to find a way to mock an `Object` created with `new` in the middle of a `method` under test.

Used Frameworks: `PHPUnit`, `Mockery`, `WP_Mock`

Example: Here I need to mock the `get_second_string()` method from the instance of the class `ExternalClass`

```
Class MyClass {

    function methodUnderTest($string) {
        $objToMock = new ExternalClass();
        $second_string = $objToMock->get_second_string();
        $final_string = $string . $second_string;
        return $final_string;
    }
}
Class TestMyClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setUp() {
    }
    public function tearDown() {
    }

    public function test_methodUnderTest() {
        $externalObject = $this->getMockBuilder('ExternalClass')
                               ->setMethods(['get_second_string'])
                               ->getMock;
        $externalObject->expects($this->once())
                       ->method('get_second_string')
                       ->willReturn(' two');
        $testObj = new MyClass();
        $this->assertEquals('one two', $testObj->methodUnderTest('one');
    }
}
```

Comment: Without refactoring the code, you're out of luck.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and what's the best way to refactor the code in your opinion? I've looked at xmike's answer, but it doesn't look very clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really have no opportunity to refactor the code or do some appropriate integration testing, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers#intercepting-object-creation and https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz/tree/PHP5

Still I think the code you make would profit a lot more from refactoring than monkey patching.

Besides, the refactoring does not need to be very heavy. You might do at least this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $externalsFactory;

    public function __construct($externalsFactory){
        $this->externalsFactory = $externalsFactory;
    }

    public function methodUnderTest($str){
        $external = $this->externalsFactory->make();
        $second_string = $external->get_second_string();
        $finalString = $str.$second_string;
        return $finalString;
    }
}

class ExternalsFactory
{
    public function make(){
        return new ExternalClass();
    }
}

class ExternalClass
{
    public function get_second_string(){
        return 'some real stuff may be even from database or whatever else it could be';
    }
}

class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $factoryMock;
    private $myClass;

    public function setUp(){
        $this->factoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('ExternalsFactory')
                                  ->getMock();
        $this->myClass = new MyClass($this->factoryMock);
    }

    public function testMethodUnderTest(){
        $extenalMock = $this->createMock('ExternalClass');
        $extenalMock->method('get_second_string')
                    ->willReturn('second');
        $this->factoryMock->method('make')
                          ->willReturn($extenalMock);
        $this->assertSame('first-and-second', $this->myClass->methodUnderTest('first-and-'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I think I'll pass the two components since they are getting old.
The refactor you suggested, on the other hand, doesn't look very clear to me. I'll provide a wider example, so it should be easier for you to point the changes needed

Comment: i've updated the sample according to the update of the question. I included dummy classes for the factory and `ExternalClass` (as you name it) to made it fully runnable.

Comment: Thank you really much, gonna figure out if creating the new class `ExternalsFactory` would be too much

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no way to do such a thing. You should pass the object as parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mock entire object.
But with phpunit you can do something like this:

```
 $f = $this->getMockBuilder(<your_class>)->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->setMethods(array(
          <mocked_method_1>, <mocked_method_2>
       ))->getMock();
```

This way, newly created object ommits constructor and you specify which method are going to behave normally and which you mock.

in testing you can specify what the method/s will return, like this:

```
$f->method(<mocked_method_1>)->willReturn(<dummy_data>);
```

using this, you will not test the mocked object in any way, but can test method which is creating the object..

Comment: I know how to mock an object, what I need is this: <br/>
`function methodUnderTest() {
    $objToMock = new someClass();
    echo $objToMock->method();
}`

Without the chance of mocking the instance of `someClass`, I can't test the `methodUnderTest`, for obvious reasons.

Comment: then you can either go with integration test (you would not need to mock the object) or create new class which extends the tested, duplicate the code and get object from factory (there could be easily mocked). But this second approach is risky, when original code changes, you would have to change testing code as well .. There is no way how to mock newly created instance of class in tested method